# If else statement based on select value to upload to different folder using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, upload

I am trying to implement a JQUERY plugin which allows me to upload images to the specified folder, however I want to base this on a select box, for example if select value "one" is selected the image will upload to folder one. I have tried to use both a switch statement and an IF statement to get this to function but have had no luck so far. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Melissa

```
<form id="myForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
</select>
 <input type="file" size="60" name="myfile">
 <input type="submit" value="Ajax File Upload">
</form>


 <div id="progress">
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="percent">0%</div >
</div>
<br/>

<div id="message"></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

var options = { 
beforeSend: function() 
{
    $("#progress").show();
    //clear everything
    $("#bar").width('0%');
    $("#message").html("");
    $("#percent").html("0%");
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
{
    $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
    $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');


},
success: function() 
{
    $("#bar").width('100%');
    $("#percent").html('100%');

},
complete: function(response) 
{
    $("#message").html("<font color='green'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");
},
error: function()
{
    $("#message").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");

}

}; 

 $("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);

});

</script>
```

Php is as follows;

```
<?php
$output_dir = "uploads/uploads";

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
//Filter the file types , if you want.
if ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"] > 0)
{
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
    //move the uploaded file to uploads folder;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);

 echo "Uploaded File :".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your select a name or ID, like

```
<select name='folder'>
```

then in your PHP page, you'll get this as part of the POST data. Check to see if it's an allowed value, and set a safe default otherwise.

```
if($_POST['folder']=='one')
   {
   $output_dir='one';
   }
elseif($_POST['folder'])=='two')
   {
   $output_dir='two';
   }
else
   {
   $output_dir='default';
   }
```

then later on,

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.'/'.$_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
```